# saving a graph for each matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, graph, save

How do I save a graph for each graph produced in a for loop?

Here is my code:

```
for frame in all_frames:
  test[frame.columns[0]].plot(kind = 'line', x = 'date')
  plt.ylabel('Percent Change from Month and Year Prior')
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add [`matplotlib.pyplot.savefig`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.savefig.html) inside the `for` loop:

```
for frame in all_frames:
    test[frame.columns[0]].plot(kind = 'line', x = 'date')
    plt.ylabel('Percent Change from Month and Year Prior')
    plt.savefig('{}'.format(frame.columns[0]))
```